# libssl.so.1.0.0: undefined symbol: EVP_idea_cbc

Tags: c, openssl

I am working on a large project that dynamically loads libssl.so.1.0.0

I get runtime error: `.../src/zwave-configurator-c: symbol lookup error: .../sdks/zwave/zware/v7.13.1/src/zwportal/install/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: undefined symbol: EVP_idea_cbc`

Using the debugger, I found out that the error occurs on the line:

```
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_IDEA
    EVP_add_cipher(EVP_idea_cbc());
#endif
```

How I can fix it?
I have Ubuntu(Xubuntu) 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: Most likely there is some library version confusion. It looks like you are using a custom version of libssl, rather than the default one that comes with Ubuntu. libssl itself depends on libcrypto - and the two normally get compiled at the same time as a pair. If the version of libssl you are using picks up at runtime some other version of libcrypto (such as the system Ubuntu version) you can end up with problems like this.

Comment: @MattCaswell how to find out which versions libssl and libcrypto are used? in the directory where libssl.so.1.0.0 is located there is also libcrypto.so.1.0.0

Comment: I'd suggest, prior to starting your process, making sure your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable includes the directory with your custom libcrypto. That should hopefully force it to use the right one.